# Can no longer scale objects in object-mode (though edit-mode works) (Gray nodes?)

Tags: scale, object-mode

Can no longer scale objects in object-mode though it works in edit-mode. I feel like I noticed the appearance of these gray nodes around the 3D view around the same time that these issues began occurring.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the *Manipulate Center Points* option enabled at the bottom of the 3d view. It's the little button with the 3 dots that is located to the right of the arrow you have pointing to the object mode menu. Click on the icon again and you should be good to go.